# Why is there no `MonadTransControl` instance for `ContT`

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I have no idea how I'd implement it and I'm assuming that there might not be a way to do it. Is there a proof or a convincing argument that it can't be done?

What makes `ContT` special?

Comment: I reckon this comments [at the definition of `ContT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#t:ContT) is relevant: "`ContT` is not a functor on the category of monads, and many operations cannot be lifted through it". You don't even need `m` to be a `Monad` to have `Monad (ContT k r m)`!

Comment: @Alec That definitely makes it weird, but it doesn't connect it with `MonadTransControl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you can, in general, get out of a `ContT r m` is a value of type `m r`. The type signature of `Run (ContT r)` would be

```
Run (ContT r) = forall n b. Monad n => ContT r n b -> n (StT (ContT r) b)
```

which is equivalent to

```
forall n b. ((b -> n r) -> n r) -> n (StT (ContT r) b)
```

The only possible type for `StT (ContT r) b` is `r`, but even then, there is no possible defined function of type `b -> n r` to pass to the `ContT`. And since `liftWith` is given a function that requires a value of type `Run (ContT r)`, it can't be implemented.

`restoreT` makes it even worse, because any value that could possibly be extracted from a general `ContT r m a` can't be turned back into a `ContT r m a`. So you lose both coming and going.

Incidentally, this is also the reason you can't make `ContT` a `MonadFix`. You can't turn an arbitrary `a` into an arbitrary `r`, and vice versa.